# add point and line layers with customized legends in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a question about plotting points and lines in the same plot using `ggplot2`. The codes for generating mock data are provided below:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(111)
x = seq(1,10,length=10)
y1 = rnorm(10, 0, 0.1)
y2 = rnorm(10, 5, 0.1)
y3 = rnorm(10, 10, 0.3)
y4 = rnorm(10, 20, 0.4)
label = c(rep("Cat",10), rep("Dog", 10), rep("Owl", 10), rep("Eagle", 10))
dat1 = data.frame(cbind(x, y=y1))
dat2 = data.frame(cbind(x, y=y2))
dat3 = data.frame(cbind(x, y=y3))
dat4 = data.frame(cbind(x, y=y4))
dat = data.frame(rbind(dat1, dat2, dat3, dat4))
dat = cbind(dat, label)
dat
```

I use the following codes to generate the plot:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=label)) + 

  geom_line(data=dat[dat$label=="Cat", ], aes(x=x, y=y, linetype=label)) +
  geom_line(data=dat[dat$label=="Dog", ], aes(x=x, y=y, linetype=label)) +

  geom_point(data=dat[dat$label=="Owl", ], aes(x=x, y=y, colour=label)) + 
  geom_point(data=dat[dat$label=="Eagle", ], aes(x=x, y=y, colour=label)) + 

  scale_color_manual("Animal", 
                     values = c("Cat" = "darkgreen",
                                "Dog" = "blue", 
                                "Owl" = "red",
                                "Eagle" = "cyan")) + 
  theme_bw() +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c(1,2)) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c(0.8, 0.8, 0.2, 0.2)) +
  scale_size_manual(values=c(1.8, 1.8, 0.6, 0.6)) +
  theme(legend.key=element_blank(),
        legend.key.width = unit(3, "line"),
        legend.key = element_blank())
```

The current plot output looks like this:
[image]

**The following points need to be changed to get my desired plot:**

1. remove the "label" legend and only show the "Animal" legend
2. for "Cat" and "Dog" legend, only show points, not lines; for "Owl" and
   "Eagle" legend, only show lines, not points
3. the line types in legend should match those in the plot
4. the order of the legend should be the same order as I specify the label: Cat, Dog, Owl and Eagle
5. I hope the lines are ticker (width=2, for example), and the points are more transparent (alpha=0.4, for example)
6. the legend position is inside the plot, not outside

   I appreciate your help/suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are using different colors and linetypes then easiest way to get legend in order you need is to change order of level in you original data frame using function `factor()`.

```
dat$label<-factor(dat$label,levels=c("Cat","Dog","Owl","Eagle"))
```

For the plot I would use only one call for the `geom_point()` and `geom_line()` and set the `colour=`, `linetype=` and `shape=` to `label` inside the `aes()` of `ggplot()`. Then using the `scale_color_manual()` set the colors you need, then with `scale_linetype_manual()` set linetypes 1 and 2 for the Cat and Dog and 0 (non-visible line) for other two levels. Inside `scale_shape_manual()` set values to NA for the Cat and Dog. In all manual scales use the same name to get only one legend. Alpha and size is changed inside the `geom_point()` and `geom_line()`. Legend position is udjusted with argument `legend.postion=` of function `theme()`.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=label,linetype=label,shape=label)) + 
      geom_point(alpha=0.4)+
      geom_line(size=2)+
      scale_color_manual("Animal", 
                         values = c("Cat" = "darkgreen",
                                    "Dog" = "blue", 
                                    "Owl" = "red",
                                    "Eagle" = "cyan"))    +
      scale_linetype_manual("Animal",values=c(1,2,0,0)) +
      scale_shape_manual("Animal",values=c(NA,NA,16,16))+
      theme_bw()+
      theme(legend.position=c(0.85,0.80))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! That's exactly what I want :)

Comment: sorry I have one more question: is there a way to hide the legend for "Eagle"? I just want to show the other three variables' legends, but in the plots, all four variables should be displayed. Thanks!

Comment: Add argument `breaks=c("Cat","Dog","Owl")` to all three `scale_...` functions

Comment: What if it wasn't points and let's say geom_segment or geom_polygon?